# In Golang I'm getting the record through exe command. how to print it line by line?

Tags: go

I want to print the results line by line.

I'm getting the record's data through exe command.

Here is the code:

```
package main

import (
"bufio"
"fmt"
"os/exec"
)

func main() {
app := "df"
//app := "buah"

arg0 := "-h"

cmd := exec.Command(app, arg0)
stdout, err := cmd.Output()

if err != nil {
    println(err.Error())
    return
}

// bytes, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(stdout)

s := bufio.NewScanner(stdout)

fmt.Println(s)

}
```

Thanks in advance.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simple:

```
a := []string{}
for s.Scan() {       
    a = append(a, s.Text())
}
```

And You have a slice of strings.

Comment: I'm getting the following Error:

`cannot use stdout (type []byte) as type io.Reader in argument to bufio.NewScanner:
 []byte does not implement io.Reader (missing Read method)`

Comment: I'm getting the output, but not with proper alignment.

Comment: What do You mean by alignment? You get every line in a slice of strings "a" and you can get every line with a[lineNumber].

Comment: Thank you kingSlayer, it was very useful.